# Запись текущего значения в сессию

Tags: php, ajax, сессия

Я пытаюсь реализовать что то вроде мультиязычности на сайте. Принцип такой: огда пользователь заходит на сайте, поставить ему язык его браузера, при желании он может изменить язык выбрав соответсвующий язык в форме.

Проблема в том что, до клика на кнопку (отправки выбранного языка на сервер) переменная `$_POST` пустая, и по этому я не могу записать его в сессию что бы сохранить язык выбранный пользователем, а после нажатия на кнопку другого языка запись в сессии не перезаписывается. Форма и `ajax` запрос:

```js
$('#multilanguage li input').click(function select_lang() {
  // id инпутов это сокращение от названия языка, так я определяю какая кнопка была нажата
  // смотрим какая кнопка была нажата
  var lang = $(this).attr('id');
  //отправляем запрос
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/header.php",
    data: {
      'lang': lang
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);

    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert('bad');
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(null);" id="multilanguage">
  <li>
    <input type="button" name="lang" value="English" id="en">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="button" name="lang" value="Russian" id="ru">
  </li>
</form>
```

Вот `php`:

```
@session_start();
//массив с языками для выбора 
$lang_arr = [
    "en" => array('English', 'Russian', 'Ukrainian'), 
    "ru" => array('Английский', 'Русский', 'Украинский')
];

//определяем язык браузера
preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(?:-[a-z]{1,8})?)(?:;q=([0-9.]+))?/', strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]), $matches); 
$langs = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]); 
foreach ($langs as $n => $v)
    $langs[$n] = $v ? $v : 1; 
arsort($langs); 
$default_lang = key($langs);
$default_lang = substr($default_lang, 0, 2); 

//если пользователь не выбирал язык
if (!isset($_POST['lang'])) {
    //проверяем совпадает ли его язык браузера с перечнем доступных языков
    if(array_key_exists($default_lang, $lang_arr)) {
        //если всё хорошо заносим его в сессию
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $default_lang;
    }else {
        //если нет, то заносим в сессию английский язык
        $_SESSION['lang']= 'en';
    }
}
//если пользователь выбрал другой язык
if(isset($_POST['lang'])) {
    //проверяем всё ли корректно
    if(array_key_exists($_POST['lang'], $lang_arr)) {
        //если всё хорошо заносим в сессию выбранный язык
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'];
    }else {
        //иначе ставим английский 
        $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
    }
}
```

Суть в том что в сессию заноситься язык браузера пользователя но когда я нажимаю на другой язык в сессию ничего не перезаписывается. подскажите, как сделать так, что бы после нажатия на кнопку обновлялась страница и в сессии менялся язык?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала измените немного вашу форму, чтобы язык был не как ID, а как свойство или атрибут кнопки. Например

```
<form id="multilanguage">
    <li>
        <input type="button" name="lang" value="English" data-lang="en">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="button" name="lang" value="Russian" data-lang="ru">
    </li>
</form>
```

Далее такой JS код, в консольке все работает четко

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="lang"]', function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var fields = new Object();

    fields.title = btn.val(); // Тайтл 
    fields.lang  = btn.attr('data-lang'); // Код


    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/header.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fields,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('beforeSend', fields);
        },
        success: function(json) {
            console.log('success', json);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: `beforSend` после нажатия отображается в консоли, а вот `success` не приходит. Скажите, почему так может быть?

Comment: Потому что вы ничего не выводите в вашем скрипте обработчике)

Comment: Добавьте в конец вашей функции exit(json_encode(['post' => $_POST]));

Comment: На страницу выводится  `{"post":[]}`, а `success` в консоли по прежнему не происходит

Comment: Попробуйте оставить только exit(json_encode(['post' => $_POST]));  а весь ваш код уберите

Comment: Ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76488/discussion-between---and-bykuznec).